# Variable scope inside php function

Tags: php, laravel, scope

I'm doing an excel file export from an eloquent model using Laravel and Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel.

Here's what I have

```
 public function export(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $this->getData($param1)->get();
        $export = Excel::create('example' . date('m-d-Y-G-His'), function ($excel) {
            $excel->setDescription('example');
        });

        $export->sheet('Example', function ($sheet) {
            $sheet->row(1, array(
                'row1',
                'row2',
                'row3'
            ));

            $i = 2;
            foreach ($data as $d) {
                $sheet->row($i, array(
                    $d->id,
                    $d->name, $d->date,
                ));
            }
        });
    }
```

And I get Undefined variable: data

I understand that is a scope problem and the error is correct, but what is the best way to pass the variable inside the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask PHP to make it available in the anonymous function with the `use` keyword:

```
$export->sheet('Example', function ($sheet) use ($data) {
```